# Postgresql multi Insert with array variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm looking to do a multiple dynamic insert with a variable array/list. The number of inserts will always vary.

I'd like to replace

```
insert into my table (col 1, col 2)
select *
from unnest(array[1, 2], array[3, 4]);
```

with

```
insert into my table (col 1, col 2)
select *
from unnest(:list-of-inserts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wrap it in a function...  this will then translate nicely into any programming language that has a data adapter for PostgreSQL, which is pretty much all of them.  As an added bonus, it will work great in psql also.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ez_insert(list1 integer[], list2 integer[])
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  rowcount integer;
BEGIN

  insert into my_table (col_1, col_2)
  values
  (unnest (list1), unnest (list2));

  GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;
  return rowcount;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Invoking:

```
select ez_insert (array[1, 2, 3], array[7, 8, 9])
```

Caveat -- if your arrays are different sizes, expect weirdness.

Here is a quick example of an implementation in C#:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select ez_insert(:ARRAY1, :ARRAY2)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("ARRAY1",
    NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("ARRAY2",
    NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = ar1;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = ar2;

int inserts = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you want to create a new Table with your data or not ?

This could be a simple :

```
SELECT * INTO table FROM unnest(array[1, 2], array[3, 4]);
```

OR

Do the same in a temporary table :

```
SELECT * INTO temp mytable FROM unnest(array[1, 2], array[3, 4]);
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO table (col 1, col 2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable;
```

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: I' like to replace SELECT * INTO table FROM unnest(array[1, 2], array[3, 4]); with SELECT * INTO table FROM unnest(:some-var); so that I can pass in a variable from a function in a programming language

Comment: In this case, you just need to create a function which will answer a list of arrays, and call it in the unnest(getMyArrays()) ... can't know how you get this list from your function to help ...